# Como modificar un dato concreto de una fila de un csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

pues eso, tengo el siguiente CSV:

```
Fila,Productos,Cantidad,Precio,Ventas
0,Gaseosa,5,2000,0
1,Agua,5,2000,0
```

digamos que vendi un agua, esta esta en la fila dos, como reflejo la venta en la columna de ventas?
porfavor ayudenme

Comment: La mejor (y probablemente unica) forma implica reescribir el archivo. Lo más cercano a borrar una parte del archivo es truncate, que, como dice su nombre, elimina todo el contenido del archivo que sigue a la posición especificada. Hay formas más y menos optimizadas de reescribir.

Comment: Osea qe tengo que volver el csv en un diccionario y editar el valor concreto y volverlo un csv otra vez

Comment: No sería lo más optimizado, ya que estarías cargando todo en memoria, pero esa sería masomenos la idea.

Answer (score 1):

Si estas usando python, usa la libreria Pandas, te puede ayudar mucho y es las mas usada para estos casos.

Primero debes crear un dataFrame de tus datos, y luego ya es usar dicha variable como una lista, pudiendo acceder a los datos mediante index.
Puedes crear el data frame directamente desde tu archivo CSV usando la function to_csv()
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "Productos": ['Gaseosa','Agua'],
    "Cantidad": [5, 5],
    "Precio": [2000, 2000],
    "Ventas": [0,0]
}

data_frame = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(data_frame)


Productos  Cantidad  Precio  Ventas
0   Gaseosa         5    2000       0
1      Agua         5    2000       0


# Use function loc to update the row and the key you want
data_frame.loc[1, ['Ventas']] = [1]

print(data_frame)


Productos  Cantidad  Precio  Ventas
0   Gaseosa         5    2000       0
1      Agua         5    2000       1
```